# Force pubkey-auth user to set password at first login

Tags: ssh, users, key-authentication

When I create a new user account I ask users to send me a public key, and want to force users to set the password the first time they log in with keypair authentication. If I create an account with an impossible/disabled and expired password, but put a pubkey in their .ssh/authorized_keys file, **the user is required to change their password at first login, but cannot enter the current one!**

```
# adduser --disabled-password foo
…
# chage -d0 foo
```

What is a more appropriate way to go about this?

Comment: If you pre-install a key for them, what's the point of ever using `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`? Any subsequent login will prefer the key.

Comment: @bahamat true, but the challenge-response thing was a tangential distraction. I've removed it from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

1. Make sure `nullok` or `nullok_secure` is not in use in arguments of `pam_unix` for `auth` in the pam configuration for any service.
2. `passwd -d foo`
3. `chage -d0 foo`

That seems to do the trick here (debian wheezy).

Comment: The two commands must be executed in the reverse order. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @Flavius, what system? That order works for me on Debian with version 4.2 of [shadow utilities](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/)